# After successful OKTA login spring boot application enters a infinite loop

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml, okta

I am trying to integrate SSO into my spring boot application. I tried to follow the tutorial mentioned at https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml and created a sample application and everything works fine and I get redirected to the Okta login page. But when I try to use the same tutorial in my application which has a context path application navigates to the OKTA login page but then enters into an infinite loop.

My application.properties file :

```
server.port = 9090
server.ssl.enabled = true
server.ssl.key-alias = spring
server.ssl.key-store = classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
security.saml2.metadata-url = https://XxxxxXXXXXXXX/sso/saml/metadata
application.baseUrl = https://localhost:9090/my_app
security.saml2.context-provider.lb.context-path=/my_app
```

My okta configurations are:

```
Single sign-on URL: https://localhost:9090/**my_app**/saml/SSO
Audience URI (SP Entity ID) : https://localhost:9090/**my_app**/saml/metadata
```

Can someone please tell me how I can configure it with context path?

```
2020-10-16 09:18:14.202  INFO 9372 --- [nio-9090-exec-9] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:9090/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;;
2020-10-16 09:18:14.996  INFO 9372 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:9090/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;;
2020-10-16 09:18:15.779  INFO 9372 --- [nio-9090-exec-6] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:9090/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;;
2020-10-16 09:18:16.512  INFO 9372 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:9090/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;;
2020-10-16 09:18:17.558  INFO 9372 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;https://localhost:9090/saml/metadata;http://www.okta.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;;;
```

Comment: Share your security config file

Comment: Hi @wak786 thank you for the reply I resolved this issue by adding context path in my security config file.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by adding following line in security config file :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(saml())
                .serviceProvider()
                .keyStore()
                .storeFilePath(this.keyStoreFilePath)
                .password(this.password)
                .keyname(this.keyAlias)
                .keyPassword(this.password)
                .and()
                .protocol("https")
                .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", "localhost", this.port))
                **.basePath("/my_app")**
                .and()
                .identityProvider()
                .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
    }
```